# In vertx, how to provide a result with a failed operation

Tags: vert.x

I'm using a service proxy to create a new record in the database for a given domain object. It delegates to a repo and then a DAO. In the case where the insert operation fails (e.g. due to a unique constraint violation) it seems as though I'm only able to return a Throwable or a String.

E.G.

```
resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(insertAsyncResult.cause()));
```

What I would like to return to the browser instead is a JSON object that looks something like this...

```
{
    error: {
        code: "VALIDATION_ERROR",
        context: {
            validationErrors: {
                username: "The username is already in use"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd also like to be able to return this from any layer in the call stack. e.g. validation on the parameters passed to the Service layer.

My problem is I don't see how to return a JsonObject in a failed future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fail the `Future` with a `ServiceException` that has an `int` failure code, a message, and an `JsonObject` containing the extra information.

As shown in the [Error Handling](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-proxy/java/#_error_handling) section of the service proxy docs:

```
if (!shoeSize.equals("9")) {
 int errorCode = 78; // can be anything
 JsonObject details = new JsonObject().put("shoeSize", shoeSize);
 resultHandler.handle(ServiceException.fail(errorCode, "The shoe size must be 9!", details);
}
```

Comment: Schoolboy error on my part, not reading the docs. Many thanks.

Comment: Now that I've got around to implementing this it still doesn't return that debugInfo JsonObject to the browser. I'm using the generated javascript service proxy. How do I get extra info back to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

`Message` class has method `fail()` for that purpose.

Try this snippet (java 8):

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer("SOME_ADDRESS", event -> {
    try {
        doSomeWork();
        event.reply("OK");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        event.fail(FAILURE_CODE, composeJson(e));
    }
});
```